# USB Wi-Fi correctly installed but it can't access the Internet, Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I have a USB Wi-Fi stick correctly installed on my Debian Wheezy system.

- from `dmesg`:

  ```
  ADDRCONF (NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
  ```
- from `ip a`:

  ```
  wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
  ...
  inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
  ...
  ```
- from `iwconfig`

  ```
  wlan0   IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:"MANUTE"
  ...
  ```

But when I ping the router I get: `Destination Host Unreachable`.

Output of `netstat -rn`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

So I guess the problem could be the first line might has as Iface
wlan0, instead of eth0.

In this case, it might be the cause of my problem. How could I change this setting?

In other cases, any guidance / advice?

For information, eth0 is the wired device name that I have unlinked since the box is far from the router. I am running a Debian Wheezy without X-Window, so I can't use any Window Network Manager, but only console.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: What does `ping -c4 192.168.1.1` return?

Comment: I couldn't try it. Strange for me, I tried http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-default-route-in-linux.html, I got an error that makes wlan0 device unavailable. I restarted the network system and still the same. I rebooted the system and at the network step same wlan0 not available message. After reboot I have unplugged the Wi-Fi stick and plug it again. Restarted the network system... and it works :S

Answer (score 0):

The route problem may be that you were using eth0 initially and so there was a default route for that interface. You may need to do an **ifdown eth0** if this happens again, in order to get rid of the unwanted route.

I will also add that I have found USB wifi adapters to almost universally crappy, and even more-so in Linux (due to closed-source drivers). I eventually got good wifi performance on Linux from a [TP-Link TL-WDN4800 PCI Card](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B007GMPZ0A/ref=pe_386430_30332290_TE_dp_1). If after a few weeks of use you really think this USB Wifi adapter is working well with Debian Wheezy, I would be interested in hearing the make/model.

Comment: I have a TP-LINK TL-WDN3200 that I use with a Jessie laptop and it works fine. Don't recall if it has a non-free firmware blob or not. Presumably wheezy (possibly with a backports kernel) would be fine too.

Comment: I hope so, since it is my tricky to keep a personal server. What I've experience is the stick goes down on suspend mode. Is is possible to turn it off this feature?

Comment: that would be [a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)